# Tag for question about obeying specific document guidelines?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

We sometimes get questions about how to configure LaTeX to follow some given guidelines / constraints set up by the OPs University or company.
One recent example is [How to set fixed (8mm) linespacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22681/how-to-set-fixed-8mm-linespacing).

I think we should create a specific tag (maybe with synonymous) for all such questions. This allows people which have to follow multiple such constraints to find all such questions easily. The tag description can then also point out that you shouldn't await good typesetting results with that settings.

I'm struggling coming up with a good name and would be happy for any suggestion.

Comment: I suggest choosing a more general title, because besides universities also other institutions, organizations and companies in general might have fixed requirements.

Comment: @Stefan: I changed the title. Please feel free to adjust it if you like.

Comment: The tag description, however, should mention that we _don't_ want people getting their work done by other people on here, but rather abstract problems and specific single issues to be solved that can be of benefit to others as well. I noticed some really localized questions on here lately and I'm afraid such a tag -- while I can totally see its purpose -- might motivate more such really specific questions.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [formatting-control](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting-control).

The tag could mark all questions which are about following such constraints, setting spacing, font size, page layout etc. manually, having full control over each aspect of the format rather than letting LaTeX macros or packages taking care.

I would prefer [typographic-control](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typographic-control) though, but I guess it's harder to find by a questioner and we would get further questions with the general [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) tag. If you perhaps like [typographic-control](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typographic-control) to be a main tag and [formatting-control](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting-control) a synonym for easy look-up, let us know in a comment.

Comment: We should however have some synonyms like `thesis-guidelines` and/or `university-guidelines` which point people there.

Comment: @Martin: yes, it would make it easier to find. Further, when we would have a [thesis guideline question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/should-we-have-a-thesis-guide-question) as suggested by Matthew we could also point to that tag.

Comment: Given some of the actual requirements people ask about conforming to, I think we should go with `stupid-guidelines`